# I can see preview but get a blank render

Tags: rendering

I have been trying to render an animation of a spaceship, but no matter what I do it comes up like this:

[image]

But I see this in the camera:

[image]

I was wondering if anybody could help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you see those icons on the top right that look like a camera? If those are off the object will not render...